# perl regex match n digits, but only if they are not all the same

Tags: regex, perl

Using a Perl regex, I need to match a series of eight digits, for example, 12345678, but only if they are not all the same. 00000000 and 99999999 are typical patterns that should not match. I'm trying to weed out obviously invalid values from existing database records.

I've got this:

```
my ($match) = /(\d{8})/;
```

But I can't quite get the backref arranged right.

Comment: Do they all have to be different?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen they do not _all_ have to be different just not all the same.  00000001 is fine, 11111111 is not

Comment: What happens is that a database field is required on a form, so the data entry people will just hold down a key to fill the field. Then sometime, months later, my script hits it. I need to weed out the obviously invalid values.

Comment: Is this an XY-problem? Do you *have* to use a regex? I would write a short subroutine such as `sub allsame { my %s; $s{$_}++ for split //, $_[0]; my $count = keys %s; return $count == 1; }`

Comment: @TLP no sir I do not have to use a regex at all.  It had a regex and it was working fine until I started seeing all these fake numbers coming through,

Comment: @carltron4000 If the numbers are coming from data entry, all the more reason to use a subroutine, so that you can add more checks as necessary.

Comment: @TLP: Please don't post code in comments

Comment: @carltron4000: What I think you need is to verify that an input field contains exactly eight digits that aren't all the same. Is that right?

Comment: @Borodin Yes, that is correct.  Sorry for the delay in answering. Had family responsibilities over the holidays.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
^(\d)(?!\1{7})\d{7}$
```

This will match 8 digit number that haven't 8 same digit.

**Sample code:**

```
my $re = qr/^(\d)(?!\1{7})\d{7}$/;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say (/$re/ ? "OK : $_" : "KO : $_");
}

__DATA__
12345678
12345123
123456
11111111
```

**Output:**

```
OK : 12345678
OK : 12345123
KO : 123456
KO : 11111111
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(\d)(?!\1{7})\d{7}$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1{7}                    what was matched by capture \1 (7 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{7}                    digits (0-9) (7 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is wrong. All you have done is post a regex together with a dump of its `YAPE::Regex::Explain` output. You don't explain *why* or *how* it could work correctly, and your pattern doesn't fulfil the requirement. Please show test cases and results.

Comment: I don't believe the automated analysis is any help to people who can't read the regex pattern. What the regex requires is "any digit, followed by seven digits different from the first".

Comment: The only strings this filters out are all of a single digit.  For example, 00001111 passes this regex.

Comment: @Miller: That is the requirement, block when all digits are the same.

Comment: @M42 The requirements were for the exact opposite.  Only if all eight digits were completely unique

Comment: @Miller: From OP's comments `they do not all have to be different just not all the same. 00000001 is fine, 11111111 is not`

Comment: Sigh, I see how you're reading it now, and yes, you are probably interpreting it correctly.  I think my interpretation was more fun though :)

Comment: @Miller: It's OK. I guess that is what the OP wants. But who knows?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this in two regular expressions.  One to match what you are looking for, and one to filter what you're not.

Inspired by HamZa's answer though, I've also provided a single regex solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $num = <DATA>) {
    chomp $num;

    # Single Regex Solution - Inspired by HamZa's code
    if ($num =~ /^.*(\d).*\1.*$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^\d{8}$/) {
        print "Yes - ";
    } else {
        print "No  - ";
    }

    # Two Regex Solution
    if ($num =~ /^\d{8}$/ && $num !~ /(\d).*\1/) {
        print "Yes - ";
    } else {
        print "No  - ";
    }

    print "$num\n";
}

__DATA__
12345678
12345674
00001111
00000000
99999999
87654321
87654351
123456789
```

And the results?

```
Yes - Yes - 12345678
No  - No  - 12345674
No  - No  - 00001111
No  - No  - 00000000
No  - No  - 99999999
Yes - Yes - 87654321
No  - No  - 87654351
No  - No  - 123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is **based** on the title of the question: *match **n** digits, but only if they are not all the same*.

---

So I've come with the following expression:

```
(\d)\1+\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\d+
```

What does this mean ?

```
(\d)                # Match a digit and put it in group 1
\1+                 # Match what was matched in group 1 and repeat it one or more times
\b                  # Word boundary, we could use (?!\d) to be more specific
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)      # Skip & fail, we use this to exclude what we just have matched
|                   # Or
\d+                 # Match a digit one or more times
```

The advantage of this regex is that you don't need to edit it each time you want to change `n`. Of course, if you want to match only `n` digits, you could just replace the last alternation `\d+` with `\d{n}\b`.

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/jZ7wF8)</kbd>

<kbd>[**SKIP/FAIL reference**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs)</kbd>

Comment: This also only filters out 8 duplicate numbers.  00001111 passes your regex.

Comment: @Miller Isn't that exactly what the OP wants ?

Comment: As I read the problem, the OP wanted to filter out all 8 digit numbers which were not completely unique:  "only if they are not all the same".  However, I took your solution and modified it to make a single regex solution that does work.  Please see my answer for those results.

Comment: Nevermind, M42 pointed out how I was making the problem more complicated than the OP intended.

Comment: @Miller To be honest, I shouldn't have answered such an unclear question. I won't argue what was the "true intention" of the OP since he doesn't seem to reply even after almost a day. I give you a +1 for your interpretation

Answer (score -2):

```
my $number = "99999999";                # look for first digit, capture,
print "ok\n" if $number =~ /(\d)\1{7}/; # use \1{7} to determine 7 matches of captured digit
```

Comment: This doesn't exclude anything around the digits, and matches if there are eight like digits in a row (even if there are more digits).

Comment: @briandfoy, that's because I specifically stated $number as such, just 8 digits. The correct implementation has to be left to the user as we do not know how those digits are generated! Don't downvote blindly.