# what pattern only match the same digits(1111) and exclude diff digits(1234)?

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to query these records , that is column `imei` is all the same digit,e.g `11111111`, `22222222`.

I tried this

```
select '111' regexp '[0-9]+'; 
> 1
```

but below is still match and it's not I want

```
select '123' regexp '[0-9]+';
>1
```

I'd like to know what pattern only match the same digits and exclude diff digits?

Comment: [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) returns **1 if expr matches pat; otherwise it returns 0.**

Comment: Not sure if MySQL's regex engine is powerful enough. Here is similar question where they solve the opposite problem (all numbers different) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749660/perl-regex-match-n-digits-but-only-if-they-are-not-all-the-same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you might have to do it a tedious way:

```
REGEXP '^(1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+|0+)$';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a back reference:

```
^(.)\1+$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/5pmGKKz8qi).

Comment: MySQL's regex engine does not support capture groups: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7058209/1233508

Comment: @DCoder oops. I'll try to resurrect this, or delete it